Is it possible to use a FileLogger in combination with a FormatLogger to write logs to file with a customizable format?
I want to add logging to an existing Julia application.
It looks like Julia supports extensive logging capabilities through the Logging.jl and other related packages. More information can be found here:

https://julialogging.github.io/

I would guess that it is possible to combine some of these components together. As far as I can tell from the somewhat limited documentation for each component, there are two components which seem relevant.

FileLogger from the LoggingExtras.jl package
FormatLogger from the LoggingExtras.jl package

Is it possible to combine these two concepts to produce a logger object which both writes to a file and allows for a user customizable logging message spec?
I tried reading the docs, and tried to combine these two items together in code, however I did not make much progress.
I believe the reason for this is the that documentation is quite limited. It says a little about what each component does, but it does not provide much, if any, information about how to compose them together.
For example, I was able to create a FileLogger instance, and write log messages to it.
using Logging, LoggingExtras

logger = FileLogger("example.log")

with_logger(logger) do
    @info "example log message"
end

However I could not figure out how to integrate a FormatLogger into this, or even if that is possible?

Partial answer
How "to produce a logger object which both writes to a file and allows for a user customizable logging message spec":
using Logging: with_logger
using LoggingExtras: FormatLogger

logger = FormatLogger() do io, args
    println(io, args._module, " | ", "[", args.level, "] ", args.message)
end

logger = FormatLogger("out.log"; append=true) do io, args
    println(io, args._module, " | ", "[", args.level, "] ", args.message)
end

with_logger(logger) do
   @info "This is an informational message."
   @warn "This is a warning, should take a look."
end

This appends to out.log:
Main | [Info] This is an informational message.
Main | [Warn] This is a warning, should take a look.

Discoverability
The above example is from the README.md at https://github.com/JuliaLogging/LoggingExtras.jl?tab=readme-ov-file#formatlogger-sink
Currently in the REPL, ?FormatLogger shows two method signatures, but no examples of the second signature with path.
FormatLogger(f::Function, path::AbstractString; append=false, always_flush=true)

This second signature is currently missing at https://julialogging.github.io/reference/loggingextras/#LoggingExtras.FormatLogger
Combining Logger Behaviors: Sinks vs. Filters
This answer does not provide a way to combine the behavior of the Sink FormatLogger with another Sink as requested, such as with FileLogger or DatetimeRotatingFileLogger.  (Maybe features like filename function or formatting function could become options with simple defaults that can be modified by Filter loggers, rather than implemented directly in Sink loggers.)

This seems to be a documentaion interpretation issue, since I tested the code in the LoggingExtras and it logs to files ok. The issue seems to be that you want to pass one sink (FileLogger) to another sink (FormatLogger or DatetimeRotatingFileLogger). You instead should pass it an IO such as gotten by io=open(filepath)or just the filename. You may have been confused by the do syntax in the example, which is the 'f' first argument.

The apparent issue is that when features are added by creating specialized sinks, the sinks cannot be used together.  Such as using DatetimeRotatingFileLogger to choose the filename, together with FormatLogger to customize what is written to the file.

So far the solution seems to be that each sink takes on the other features.  So the FormatLogger can also log to a file like FileLogger, and DatetimeRotatingFileLogger can take a format function like FormatLogger.  These additional features are not apparent from the names; from the names I might expect an orthogonal design where I need to compose them to get both features.
